# Server or Desktop for web development

Tags: server, development

I apologize ahead of time if this is a repeat question. I'm a linux noob and want to use it for website development. I installed the Server version and got a working LAMP installed via the command line. However, I don't see any web browser. How will I be able to view/test my site as I'm developing if I can't install a major browser, e.g Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc. Is the solution to use Ubuntu Desktop instead? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server is what it is advertised as - a Server. While you can develop using command line tools, it will be a major pain in the @$$. With that, you can install the Ubuntu Desktop version and install the LAMP or LEMP stack (whichever you prefer) after.

Basically, you have two options.

1. If you have already installed Ubuntu Server, you can just add in the Ubuntu Desktop package by issuing the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.
2. If you have Ubuntu Desktop installed, issue the following command on the terminal to install the LAMP Stack : `sudo apt-get install tasksel && sudo tasksel`. Once `tasksel` starts, you can install the LAMP Stack.

I would however recommend you to try out LEMP (NGINX instead of Apache2). If you would like to do that, follow the instructions on [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04).